# Change tint on a sprite with phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a sprite representing a character in Phaser 2.3.0.

I want to change all the red tint in this sprite by another tint keeping the same luminosity.

I don't want to change other color than red, so the tint property doesn't help me.

Is there an easy way to do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there's no "easy" way to do this really. The tint effect is additive across the whole image, not one colour channel.

You could draw the image to a BitmapData and then use its ability to process pixels (or replace colours) to create the effect you want. But if you're doing this a lot (i.e. with lots of different objects, or animated sprites, or large images, or lots of different colours), or in hot areas of your code then it's not a great idea. It uses extra memory and more importantly processing time as each pixel is recoloured.

If you only ever need one fixed tint colour, and you don't need to apply it to lots of sprites, then personally the fastest way (from a rendering perspective) is to have red tinted sprites in your sprite sheets. Uses more memory and load time, but decreases processing time to nothing.

Depending entirely on your type of game you should know for yourself which option sounds best, as it's not a "one hat fits all" problem.

Comment: In fact I've some sprite with a special flashy color that is supposed to change depending another color the player chosen. I suppose I will need to do some bitmapdata manipulation. I expected something magic like changeTint(from, to)  :) Thanks!